# Call twig template in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have a json api with symfony2:

```
return new JsonResponse(array(
    'deliveryRange' => $deliveryRange,
    'html' => $this->render(':App:Command/deliveryRange.html.twig'),
));
```

The delivery range is an Array, the html variable send me back my twig template.

Here is my JS:

```
callDeliveryRange: function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Command.routeApiRange,
        cache: false,
        data: {},

        success: function (data, status) {
            Command.htmlDeliveryRange(data);
        },
    })
},

htmlDeliveryRange: function(data){
    $('#content-delivery-range').html(data.html);
},
```

In the htmlDeliveryRange function I would like to append the twig template in my new twig file.

But nothing is happening.

And I would like also to use the variable of data.deliveryRange in the template.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just:

```
return new JsonResponse([
   'deliveryRange' => $deliveryRange,
   'html'          => $this->renderView(':App:Command/deliveryRange.html.twig'),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, And How can I use the variable `$deliveryRange` in this template?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->renderView()` instead of `render()` method. `renderView()` returns content of twig template as string, while `render()` returns `Response` object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do:

```
$lReturn['html'] = $this->renderView(':App:Command/deliveryRange.html.twig');
$lReturn['deliveryRange'] = $deliveryRange;

return new Response(json_encode($lReturn), 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
```